# Unable to pass parameter after submitting form

Tags: forms, jsp, parameters

I recorded a 15 seconds video to show this error: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LYQ4pjo5rV8

I am trying to make a web application for admin to manage members.

So, admin can selected update action or delete action from dropdown list to be performed for a specific member.

`onchange` is set for the dropdown list.

Therefore, if admin selected a action, the form will be submitted to `MemberAdmin` servlet.

And then `MemberAdmin` will perform the update or delete function to the member.

I faced difficulties to pass a parameter to my servlet.

Even though I am using `get` method for the form, my servlet unable to receive any parameter.

I expecting to have url like

```
http://localhost:8080/Assignment/MemberAdmin?action=update~M0001
```

But I am getting this url:

```
http://localhost:8080/Assignment/MemberAdmin?
```

`update` - selected action

`~`      - act as separator

`M0001`  - member id

After obtaining all the members' data from the database, I print out row by row.

Is there any wrong with my `form`?

```
<%@page import="java.sql.Date"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="domain.Member"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<jsp:useBean id="memberControl" 
             class="control.MemberControl" scope="page" >
</jsp:useBean>

<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

        <title>Environmental Society</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#myTable').DataTable();
            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function actionFunc(sel) {
                if (sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text === "Delete") {
                    if (confirm("Confirm to delete this member?")) {
                        document.getElementById("actionForm").submit();
                    }
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("actionForm").submit();
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body id="body">    
        <div id="bodyContent" style="color: black; overflow-y: scroll;">
                <%
                    ArrayList<Member> member = new ArrayList<Member>();
                    member = memberControl.getAllRecord();
                %>
                <h3 style="text-align: left">Select the member you wish to update:</h3>
                <p>
                <table class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="myTable" style="padding-top: 5px">
                    <!--column width-->
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="memberAdmin">
                            <th class="memberAdmin">No</th>
                            <th class="memberAdmin">ID</th>
                            <th class="memberAdmin">Name</th>
                            <th class="memberAdmin">Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <%
                        for (int i = 0; i < member.size(); i++) {
                            String id = member.get(i).getId();
                            String name = member.get(i).getName();
                    %>
                    <form action="../MemberAdmin" method="get" id="actionForm" name="actionForm">
                        <tr class="memberrow">
                            <td class="member"><%=i + 1%></td>
                            <td class="member"><%=id%></td>
                            <td class="member"><%=name%></td>
                            <td class="member">
                                <select name="action" id="action" onchange="actionFunc(this)">
                                    <option disabled selected value>- select action -</option>
                                    <option value="update~<%=id%>">Update</option>
                                    <option value="delete~<%=id%>">Delete</option>
                                </select>
                                <button type="submit" value="submit" name="button" hidden=""></button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </form>
                    <%}%>
                </table>
                </p>
        </div>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated. I been solving this for many hours.

*There is no web.xml error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out there is a problem with my javascript

Changed `document.getElementById("actionForm").submit();` to `sel.form.submit();`

Because each row has the form with `id="actionForm"` due to the looping.

So maybe compiler doesn't know which form I really want to submit.

```
    function actionFunc(sel) {
        if (sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text === "Delete") {
            if (confirm("Confirm to delete every thing about the member?")) {
                sel.form.submit();
            }
        } else {
            sel.form.submit();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your output in video it's clearly telling null pointer exception means not getting the parameter value which you are using in further server side process.

Can you tell in server side how you are trying to get it?

It should be like request.getParameter("action"), you will get the right value. getParameter is for retrieving parameters from form data and URL query string. Make sure you are not using getAttribute which is for transfer data through the process chain during the request life cycle.

Still if you have doubt in your form than hard code value of your option and try to check it's working as expected.

Comment: My servlet is correct. I solved this problem. Thanks, for your answer.